# Insurance when Travel Insurance companies don't cover your destination

Tags: insurance, new-zealand, iran

We're living in New Zealand, and we're going to visit Iran (our home country) for a month. New Zealand put Iran on the "not safe to travel" list, so no insurance company covers us.

We're wondering if there's anything else we can do? For example, cover for the flights or lost luggage only.

I understand the insurance companies don't want to take the risk. However, the last time we traveled to Iran, our luggage was lost on a connecting flight in Australia. The flight was from Dubai to Melbourne then to Auckland, and had nothing to do with Iran's situation. (Well actually it was more than just a lost suitcase but don't want to make the post too long.)

So I wonder if there are other types of cover we can get? For the part of the trip that is not related to Iran's situation. i.e. the flight. Or maybe, we can buy a cover from a company in another country other than New Zealand?

Comment: Why can't you just get insurance from NZ to Dubai and back and leave Iran non-covered?

Comment: Have you tried searching for eg ‘high risk travel insurance’? Some companies will offer cover when travelling against government advice eg in the UK https://www.insurewithease.com/high-risk-travel-insurance#:~:text=High%20risk%20travel%20insurance%20includes,Foreign%20and%20Commonwealth%20Office%20advice

Comment: Also check if any ‘personal possessions away from home’ cover included in your home insurance contents would still be valid in this situation.

Comment: Have you tries buying this insurance from Iranian insurer? I believe they would cover travel to them. The market may be not as developed as in Australia, though.